# Wait for LiveData result in a Kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have a repository class with an asynchronous method returning `User` wrapped into a `LiveData`:

```
interface Repository {
    fun getUser(): LiveData<User>
}
```

In a ViewModel's coruotine scope I want to wait for a result of `getUser()` method and use an `User` instance.

this is what, I am looking for:

```
private fun process() = viewModelScope.launch {
   val user = repository.getUser().await()
   // do something with a user instance
}
```

I could not find `LiveData<>.await()` extension method, and any attempts to implement it.
So before doing it my self, I wonder maybe there is some better way?

All solutions that I have found were about making `getUser()` a `suspend` method, but what if I can not change `Repository`?

Comment: You can't "await" a LiveData.  You `observe()` its changes, and decide what you want to do with the current value in the callback.

Comment: Yes, but this way we are going back to callbacks from coroutines

Comment: Coroutines and observers are not really interchangeable concepts.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to create an `await()` extension function using `suspendCancellableCoroutine()`. This probably is not exactly correct, but something along these lines should work:

```kotlin
public suspend fun <T> LiveData<T>.await(): T {
  return withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
      val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(value: T) {
          removeObserver(this)
          continuation.resume(value)
        }
      }

      observeForever(observer)

      continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
        removeObserver(observer)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should return the first value emitted by the `LiveData`, without leaving an observer behind.

Comment: I think you might need to wrap this function in `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`, since `observeForever` can only be called on the main thread. Unless, I suppose, you're following a convention that all suspend functions are safe to call only from the Main dispatcher.

Comment: @Tenfour04: Good point -- I have updated the example, though I used `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`. Thanks!

Comment: I'd argue that it is safer to as `asFlow().first()`. `invokeOnCancellation` is called synchronously which is a little worrying.

Comment: @DominicFischer: That's a simpler possibility, albeit with more "moving parts" under the covers. `asFlow()`, as currently constructed, uses a conflated `Channel` as an intermediary between the `LiveData` and the resulting `Flow`, and that worries me a bit -- you might not strictly get the first object returned from the `LiveData`.

Comment: We can meet in the middle with a `CompletableDeferred`.

Comment: @DominicFischer: That's an interesting option. Though the function name `completeExceptionally()` makes me giggle. :-)

Comment: Since `continuation.invokeOnCancellation()` can be invoked on any thread, it's important to ensure we are on the main thread by posting a message on a Handler before calling `removeObserver(observer)`

Answer (score 1):

```
suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineWithTimeout(
    timeout: Long,
    crossinline block: (CancellableContinuation<T>) -> Unit
): T? {
    var finalValue: T? = null
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeout) {
        finalValue = suspendCancellableCoroutine(block = block)
    }
    return finalValue
}

suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineObserverWithTimeout(
    timeout: Long,
    data: LiveData<T>,
    crossinline block: (T) -> Boolean
): T? {
    return suspendCoroutineWithTimeout<T>(timeout) { suspend ->
        var observers : Observer<T>? = null
        val oldData = data.value
         observers = Observer<T> { t ->
             if (oldData == t) {
                 KLog.e("参数一样,直接return")
                 return@Observer
             }
             KLog.e("参数不一样,刷新一波")
            if (block(t) && !suspend.isCancelled) {
                suspend.resume(t)
                observers?.let { data.removeObserver(it) }
            }
        }

        data.observeForever(observers)
        suspend.invokeOnCancellation {
            KLog.e("删除observiers")
            observers.let { data.removeObserver(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The previous @EpicPandaForce answers have been answered very well, I added a type judgment on this basis, and I will return only when the conditions are met. Sorry, my English is not very good.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, thanks @Tyler2P

Answer (score 0):

here is an extension function that suits your needs, this function also include maximum wait time parameter.

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
    time: Long = 2,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }
    this.observeForever(observer)

    afterObserve.invoke()

    // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
    if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
        this.removeObserver(observer)
        throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}
```

Answer (score -1):

True Kotlin way was to change Repository interface and make getUser() a suspend method.

Comment: so you don't actually need the LiveData, just the User?

Comment: Yes on the repository layer its better use `suspend fun getUser(): User`.

Comment: if you want to get User then sure, but if you want to get LiveData<User> to display stuff suspend is not necessary

Answer (score -1):

You can actually "await" for live data inside coroutine

it is a workaround, there might be better options:

```
suspend fun retrieveUser(): LiveData<User> {
     val liveUser: MutableLiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()

     var counter = 0
     val timeOut = 20 // 2 sec

     while(liveUser.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
          if(counter > timeout) break
          counter++
          delay(100)
     }

     return liveUser
```

Comment: Don't use `delay` as workaround