# Fetch all with LiveData Room Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am using Room in my project and I want to get list from the DB but I get null although anytime I don't use live data, I get the values so I know the data is available in the database.

```
@Dao
interface AddressDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(address: Address): Long

    @Query("SELECT * from address")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<MutableList<Address>>
}


@Entity(tableName = "address")
data class Address(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0L)

class AddressDbRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val addressDao: AddressDao
) {
    suspend fun insertAddress(address: Address): Long = addressDao.insert(address = address)

    fun getAll(): LiveData<MutableList<Address>> = addressDao.getAll()
}

@HiltViewModel
class AddressViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val addressDbRepository: AddressDbRepository,
    @DefaultDispatcher private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
): ViewModel() {

    private var _events2 = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Address>>()
    val events2: LiveData<MutableList<Address>> = _events2
    fun getAddress() {
        job?.cancel()

        val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
            val message = when (throwable) {
                is HttpException -> throwable.toErrorMessage()
                else -> "An Error Occurred."
            }
            Log.d(
                "PLACE_SEARCH_VIEWMODEL ERROR",
                "PLACE_SEARCH_VIEWMODEL RESPONSE ERROR ${throwable.localizedMessage}"
            )
            Log.d(
                "PLACE_SEARCH_VIEWMODEL ERROR",
                "PLACE_SEARCH_VIEWMODEL RESPONSE ERROR ${message}"
            )
        }
        job = viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
            val resp = withContext(defaultDispatcher) {
                addressDbRepository.getAll()
            }

            _events2.value = resp.value
            Log.d("PLACE_ADDY_VIEWMODEL", "PLACE_ADDY_VIEWMODEL RESPONSE ${resp}")
        }
    }
}
```

Any help as to how I can get the value would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this code:

```
    job = viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
        val resp = withContext(defaultDispatcher) {
            addressDbRepository.getAll()
        }

        _events2.value = resp.value
        Log.d("PLACE_ADDY_VIEWMODEL", "PLACE_ADDY_VIEWMODEL RESPONSE ${resp}")
    }
```

First of all, you don't need to specify a dispatcher to call `getAll()` because it instantly returns a LiveData without blocking.

When you check its `value` property immediately after it's created, it will not have received its first value yet because it is doing an asynchronous IO operation under the hood to retrieve that first value.

A LiveData is kind of inconvenient to use with a coroutine, as it has no mechanism to wait for its first result. You could write an [extension function like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62474768/506796) (note the final comment on that answer however--I think you need to get a main handler and post the code in the cancellation block), or you can cheat and turn it into a Kotlin Flow and await the first result by calling `asFlow().first()` on it. Alternatively, you could make the source function return Flow instead of LiveData to take one step out.

You also might consider changing your function into a `suspend` function that returns `MutableList<Address>` directly if you don't need to observe this value for changes elsewhere. The point of having a DAO function that returns a LiveData or Flow is so you can subscribe to it and get updates every time the database changes. When you want to fetch the current value one time, a suspend function is more appropriate. But if you have need of both, the `flow.first()` method is fine and avoids having to create multiple version of your DAO getters.

Comment: So the dispatcher was specified when I removed the live data. Thank you though.

Comment: Wow. What an amazing answer. Thank you very much. Helped me in my case.